# Simples curves on $RP^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A subset $\Sigma $ of a space is a simple closed curve if it is homeomorphic
to S1. Let $p: S^2 \rightarrow RP^2$ be the canonical projection of the sphere
onto the projective plane. Prove that if $\Sigma$ is a simple closed curve
in $R P^2$ then $p^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is either a simple closed curve in $S^2$ or is a
union of two disjoint simple closed curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is a double cover of $\Sigma$, which is either a circle or a disjoint union of two circles. If $\Sigma$ represents the generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2)$, then $p^{-1}(\Sigma)$ is a circle. Otherwise $p^{-1}(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ is a disjoint union of two circles.

Comment: Would someone please explain the downvoting?

Comment: You are not the only victim. All the questions and answers posted around half an hour ago are down-voted.

Comment: Excuse, but I don´t understand you  Why I can think $\Sigma$ like the generator.

Comment: Because in fact, I think that you don´t proof anything

Comment: @John That's weird. Though I'm not new to downvoting, I was just perplexed to see an answer without any discernible mistake get downvoted.

Comment: It happens sometimes (serial downvote on all the newest posts). Just take it as a noise....

Comment: @SergioTroncosoIgua : It seems that your opinion explain why your question was down-voted.

Comment: But, I don´t  down-voted.